# Date and Month formatting issue into Excel from DF

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

On Python 3.9 and Pandas 1.3.4.

So I'm trying to format 2 columns of my df and export it to excel. These 2 columns are date and month. Date is supposed to be formatted as `%m/%d/%y` and Month is supposed to be formatted as `%B %Y`.

When I do `print(df['Date'])` and `print(df['Month'])` it prints `01/04/22` and `January 2022` respectively. However when I do `df.to_csv(file.csv)` it shows in excel as `1/4/2022` and `Jan-22`. I would like it to be formatted as `01/04/22` and `January 2022` respectively. How can I solve this?

This is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(file.csv, dtype=str))

df["Date"] = pd.Timestamp("today").strftime("%m/%d/%y")
df["Month"] = pd.Timestamp("today").strftime("%B %Y")

print(df["Date"])
print(df["Month"])

df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

NOTE: `to_excel` fixed this issue

Comment: If you need an Excel file, probably better to use `to_excel` instead of `to_csv`.

Comment: @BigBen oh this literally just fixed my issue, thanks